# php echo exit() and optional field

Tags: php, mysql, echo, exit

two trivial matters:

i've this PHP control script used to update optional fields into a database:

```
if(strlen($nome) == ""){$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio; }
elseif(strlen($nome) < 2 || strlen($nome) > 20 )
    {echo('Se vuoi modificare il campo nome, assicurati che lo 
         stesso sia superiore ai 2 caratteri ed inferiore ai 20!</br>'); exit();}
```

1. how do I print out the script content in echo in the same page of my form ?

if I remove exit the script "Se vuoi modificare il campo nome..." is print in the same page, but the database is incorrectly populated with the wrong information. as if the control script would serve only to print it,
without blocking the user. it is as if the control script would serve only to print me the phrase contained in echo how can I do to fix it?

2. the script for optional field

if(strlen($nome) == ""){$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio; }

does not work: i want that if user wants to update is name, he must insert a word including by 2 and 20 letters, but if he doesn't want to update the field, he can also not fill it, and the database should not overwrite anything, keeping the name previously entered (in the registration phase , for example )
how can i do this?

#### Edit:

thank to you for your answers, I try to do @Michael Johnson method and @Valkyrurr method too, but nothing.

1. the script:

   header('Location: "errore.php"')

doesn't work! in the page errore.php i put:

```
<?php
// Includo la connessione al database
require('config.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{ header('Location: login.php'); exit; }

echo('Se vuoi modificare il campo nome, assicurati che lo 
             stesso sia superiore ai 2 caratteri ed inferiore ai 20!<br>');
?>
```

but it compares: Access denied! Error 403...

and 2. this script:

```
$nome = trim($nome); 
if (strlen($nome) == 0) {
$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio;}
```

overwrites the field in my database with "".

To explain better the way which i work on the code, I post you all I write, perhaps this another error I've never seen or I've never consider like an error! I hope that you understand my spaghetti English! :)

```
    if(isset($_POST['modifica_dati'])) 
    {
$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
    $query_nome =  mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM utenti WHERE id = '" .             $_SESSION['login'] . "' LIMIT 1");  
    $row_nome = mysql_fetch_array($query_nome);
    $nome_vecchio = $row_nome['nome'];
     
    $nome = trim($nome); // Make sure there are no extra spaces at beginning or end
    if(strlen($nome) == 0){$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio; }
    if(strlen($nome) < 2 || strlen($nome) > 20 )
        {
          header('Location: "errore.php"')
         echo('Se vuoi modificare il campo nome, assicurati che lo 
             stesso sia superiore ai 2 caratteri ed inferiore ai 20!</br>');      exit();} 
        
    if (is_numeric($nome)) 
        {echo('Se vuoi modificare il campo nome, assicurati che lo 
             stesso non cntenga numeri al suo interno!<br>'); exit();}   
             
    // verifico che il nome non contenga caratteri nocivi
    elseif (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z \'-]+$/i',$nome)) {
        echo 'Il nome contiene caratteri non ammessi!<br>'; exit();}
   }
```

Where it's wrong?

Comment: `strlen()` function returns int, not an empty string.

Comment: i've tried also with  if( $nome == ""){$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio; } and with the same result...

Comment: Correct way would be `if( (int)strlen($nome) < 1 )`.

Comment: i tried with if( (int)strlen($nome) < 1 ) but it overwrites the db with " ", rather than writes the name included yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. For your 2nd `if()` statement, before the `echo` `exit()`, issue a redirect call. Like so, `header('Location: "script_name_here.php"')`
2. The `strlen()` in the condition returns an int, so compare it to `0` and not to `""`. Like so, `if(strlen($nome) == 0){ }`

Answer (score 1):

Displaying the message on the form page can be done in a couple ways. If you display the form with the same script that processes it, you could put the message in a variable and display it later. You will, of course, need additional code to prevent the database from being changed (maybe something like adding a `$_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio;` instead of the exit.

Redirecting as suggested by @Valkyrurr would also be possible, if you scripts are separate. You will need to provide a way to indicate the error.

As mentioned elsewhere, `strlen()` isn't being used correctly. I'd suggest something like

```
$nome = trim($nome); // Make sure there are no extra spaces at beginning or end
if (strlen($nome) == 0) {
    $_POST['nome'] = $nome_vecchio;
}
```